# Ionic 4 custom pipe works fine in app.component.html but not work at other .html pages(works at .ts file)

Tags: pipe, angular7, ionic4

I tried to create a custom pipe on Ionic 4. When I use this pipe at app.component.html it works fine but in other .html pages it says "The pipe couldn't be found". Also it works at all .ts files if imported. How can I use pipe at .html pages. Thanks in advices.

```
src/pipes/pipes.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SearchfilterPipe } from './searchfilter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [SearchfilterPipe],
  exports: [SearchfilterPipe]
})
export class PipesModule { }

/src/pipes/searchfilter.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform,Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchfilter',
  pure:false
})
@Injectable()
export class SearchfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return null;
  }

}

/app.module.ts


import { PipesModule } from '../pipes/pipes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,HttpClientModule,FilterPipeModule,FormsModule,PipesModule],
  providers: [

    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Crop,
    ImagePicker,
    File



  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Import pipe module in which page you are using

Comment: When I import it in homepage.page.ts  I can't use it like *ngFor="let oB of  ogretmenBilgi | searchFilter:'something' "   it says pipe not found. But I can use it in homepage.page.ts as this.searchFilter.transform();

Comment: After importing pipesmodule to "homepage.module.ts" instead of homepage.page.ts now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to reply my own question. And I'm happy to find solution for "The pipe couldn't be found". I spent more than 1 day and I don't want to anyone spend time for this.

1) Firstly, create pipes folder in src/app folder (in app folder).

2) Second, on cmd "ionic generate pipe pipes/searchfilter"  => this will generate two files in pipes.

3 Third, create file in pipes folder with name "pipes.module.ts"
and write below code to => "pipes.module.ts"

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SearchfilterPipe } from './searchfilter.pipe';  //our pipe which we generate

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [SearchfilterPipe],
  exports: [SearchfilterPipe]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

Now we have PipesModule we can generate more pipes and write them in pipesmodule. We will import only PipesModule instead of all pipes.

4) You do not have to import PipesModule in app.module.ts

5) Now go to page which you want to use pipe and open for example "anasayfa.module.ts"
and import "PipesModule" and write it in @ngModel imports(it will be created automatically)
Please be careful you will import PipesModule to something.MODULE.TS not something.page.ts